# String.replaceAll() throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, when I call `replaceAll()` with replacement text containing `$1`:

This is from a more complex code, but I simplified it as follows:

http://ideone.com/QCof3

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test = "@Key";
        String replacement = "$1";
        test = test.replaceAll("@Key", replacement);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:470)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:737)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
    at Test.main(Main.java:5)
```

Are there any workarounds for this issue? I do not want to use a 3rd party library.

Comment: With `replaceAll` that would be *expected* behaviour.

Comment: You're asking about a `NullPointerException` yet the stack trace is for an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Why is it expected? I don't see any restrictions on replacement string in method documentation.

Comment: Have suggested a mod amend the post title, since this isn't a bug in the API either.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS, you're inserting regular expressions in a string which you apply regular expressions to. It's only natural that those expressions get evaluated too.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html clearly indicates that regular expression matching is used by replaceAll.

Comment: @mcfinnigan What I understand from that description is that it's the 1st argument that is regular expression. There is no restriction on 2nd argument in the doc.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS - ok, interesting.  It turns out that String.replaceAll() calls Matcher.replaceAll() internally - hence the issue, since Matcher sees $ and a number immediately afterwards and assumes that is a regex group parameter.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Oh, I see now, it is explained on the bottom. My bad: "Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string;"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try with the replace() only

```
test = test.replace("@Key", replacement);
```

Comment: I need to replace all occurences.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS: `replace()` actually replaces all occurences as well. The only difference is that `replaceAll()` takes regexps.

Answer (score 7):

`String replacement = "\\$1";`

should resolve it.  $ is a regex control character, so just like any other control character it must be escaped.  Java being java, the escape has to be a double backslash.

Comment: how can I programmatically escape `$`?

Comment: append a backslash in front of it whenever you detect it in an input stream.

Comment: `replacement = replacement.replaceAll("$", "\\$");` When I do that I get `replacement = "\\$1$"`

Comment: because it is the FIRST parameter that must be a regular expression. '$' by itself matches either a group if it has a numeral, or the end of the current line if it does not.

Answer (score 7):

If you really need the regex in String.replaceAll() instead of just the String.replace(), which really does replace all strings but just does not use regex,  you can use Matcher.quoteReplacement()

```
String stringwithgroup = "Give me all your $$$$";
String result = proposal.replaceAll("Marry me",Matcher.quoteReplacement(stringwithgroup));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Matcher.quoteReplacement has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String test = "@Key";
    String replacement = "\\$1";
    test = test.replaceAll("@Key", replacement);
    System.out.println(test);
```

---

- [IDEOne Demo](http://ideone.com/P3aPR)

Comment: how can I programmatically escape `$`?

Comment: if  `"$1".equals(replacement){/*do stuff*/}` , may be `contains()`

Comment: I need to be able to replace any string such as `"abcd$xabcd"`. How do I do that programatically? replacement = replacement.replaceAll("$", "\\$"); When I do that I get replacement = "\\$1$"

Comment: May be you can use some reg-ex pattern to do this

Answer (score 2):

Check your regular expression. You want to catch the first group that was selected in your regular expression. But your regular expression is only $1. This means that it takes the first group. But there is no such group, so there is the exception.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

Try using this command with this regular expression.

```
Class Test {  
   public static void main(String args[]) {  
      String test = "@Key";  
      String replacement = "!!$1";  
      test = test.replaceAll("(@Key)", replacement);  
      System.out.println(test);  
   }  
}
```

The result is `test = !!@Key`. Because the first group is @Key and replacement by !!@Key.

Please check there links for rugular expressions. [Lesson REGEX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
And: [Search and replace with regular expressions](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace.shtml)

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

This is what you need to do:

```
String test = "@Key";
String replacement = "\\$1";
test = test.replaceAll("@Key", replacement);
System.out.println(test);
```

**Use of $#**

'$#', '#' being a number in the second argument of replaceAll means it will get the 1st group of matches. So to use it correctly, here's an example:

```
String test = "World Hello!!!";
String replacement = "$2 $1";
test = test.replaceAll("(World) (Hello)", replacement);
System.out.println(test);
```

You create groups with the brackets, and the code take the two groups and swap them around.

**Use of $**

'$' in regular expression means the end of the line. So by using '$' as the first argument in replaceAll, will append to the end of the string, ie:

```
String test = "World Hello!!!";     
test = test.replaceAll("$", " ~ a java dev");
System.out.println(test);
```